# Running myBB forum within Zend Framework

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, frameworks, forum, mybb

I have a simple Zend Framework site I am developing with the addition that there is a myBB forum for the same site.

I placed the forum (In a folder called 'forum' within the public folder of the Zend scaffolding but issues are created in that the .htaccess that controls the URL rewrite causes issues for the forum.

I then placed the forum outside of the public folder. This works fine only if I remove the .htaccess, but then Zend obviously doesn't work.

How can I get the .htaccess rewrite to work such that if the url http://www.mysite.com/forum is used it wont rewrite the url for the Zend Framework, anything else and it should forward to the public folder.

My webroot .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

TIA
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess amended as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteRule ^(forum)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the htaccess file in your forum's folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Without any rules. This will make it so rules from the parent directory won't get applied.